Missing required modules: 'FirebaseCore' after updating to Xcode 15.4
I updated my MacOS to Sonoma and thus Xcode to 15.4. After updating Xcode and reinstalling Firebase packages (11.2.0 but also tried older versions) I am getting error flags in the files that were previously working.
'import FirebaseFirestore' gives an error of Missing required modules: 'FirebaseCore', 'FirebaseFirestoreInternalWrapper'
This was not happening before the update. FirebaseCore is shown on the left hand panel under Package Dependencies, but I cannot add FirebaseCore to package dependencies under the 'General' tab of my project name.
I have tried installing older versions of Firebase. I am installing Firebase through the Xcode Package Manager.

I was able to resolve it by downgrading the Firebase pods to version 10.22.0. After downgrading, I cleared the DerivedData folder, performed a clean build, and then rebuilt the app. Everything is running smoothly now.
Here's the relevant pod configuration:
pod 'FirebaseCore', '~> 10.22.0'
pod 'FirebaseFirestore', '~> 10.22.0'
pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics', '~> 10.22.0'
pod 'FirebaseAnalytics', '~> 10.22.0

'
It seems to be an issue on Firebase's end, and hopefully, it will be resolved in future updates.
